# Maintenance of free and paid app on AppStore

Tags: iphone, ios

I tried searching for reference about this and I have not been able to find any. I am wondering if there is a way to submit 1 binary to AppStore for two different versions of app: 1 free with ads and 1 paid without app.

How would it be possible for me then to convert the free version to the paid and ad-free version once the user has paid? Is there no way to do this under 1 binary? Do I always need to maintain 2 binaries for this?

Comment: I would suggest you to create a free app with ads where the user can remove the ads with In-App-purchase.

Comment: As Mattias states, you may be interested in looking at in-app purchase. See https://developer.apple.com/appstore/in-app-purchase/index.html and http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4009 and https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html for more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more a business decision from your side, you can have 1 binary and switch to paid version (no ad, new features) done in your code and use "In App purchase" payment method.

[In App Purchase Method Link](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/in-app-purchase/index.html)

Comment: the problem with 2 different binaries is that if i use game center i am assuming that the two binaries cannot use the same leaderboards etc etc?

Comment: I personally find 2 binaries (free and paid) a bad marketing approach. I'd rather make one free and charge the user after he gets more dependent of my App by desiring the locked features

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a separate license app that the single binary checks for then unlocks the paid content?  Many Android applications have this, I am not sure if iOS allows this, though.